# MongoDb: $geoIntersects for multiple input coordinates

Tags: mongodb, geospatial

I have a list of coordinates for each of them I need to perform [$geoIntersects](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/geoIntersects/) query. For one coordinate the query looks like this:

```
db.polygons.find({ 
    geometry: { 
        $geoIntersects: {
            $geometry: {
                type: "Point", coordinates: [24.053640, 49.812427]
            } 
        } 
    } 
})
```

The problem is that there is a list of input coordinates and for each of them I need to find a polygon. The only way I've found so far is to iterate over them in application code and execute query N times.

Is it possible to do it with one MongoDB query? If not, any ideas on how this can optimized are appreciated.

Comment: Did you try with the MultiPoint geometry type and the corresponding array of coordinates pairs?

Comment: @lusitanica indeed, that works! please post an answer and I will be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possible solution is replacing the Point geometry type with the MultiPoint one, and passing in the the list of input coordinates as an array.

```
db.polygons.find({ 
geometry: { 
    $geoIntersects: {
        $geometry: {
            type: "MultiPoint", coordinates: [[24.053640, 49.812427],[...]...] 
        } 
    } 
} 
})
```

Comment: I can confirm it works, the command I've used:

db.polygons.find({ 
    geometry: { 
        $geoIntersects: {
            $geometry: {
                type: "MultiPoint", coordinates: [[24.053640, 49.812427],[...]...]
            } 
        } 
    } 
})

Comment: @LuisTavares suggestion: add the result (comment) of Yuriy and embed it in your answer.